# php why new DateTime ('now') returns 1970 after 2038

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I decided to check the end of the unix epoch, so I change the date more than 2038 in my calendar.
I surprized that the:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');    echo $now->format('Y-m-d');
```

**RETURNS 1970-01-01 !**

```
$now = new DateTime();
```

returns same and php 5.4 returns same.
However:

```
$now = new DateTime('9000-10-01');
```

returns 9000-01-01.
**How to get current date after 2038 using DateTime?**

My OS: winxp x32 and php 5.3/5.4 x86.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Move to a 64-bit system and 5.2+ and you are good to go beyond 2038

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to get current date after 2038 using DateTime?"

I'd consider using a fully 64 bit stack and OS. And by the way, the unix timestamp convention is not used only in unix/linux.

See [php time function](http://php.net/time) as a good example. This function cannot give a result for dates after 2038, if you use only 32 bits integers.

Comment: You are right. php x64 doesn't have such problems. It's problem only in php x86 (even in Windows 7 x64).